# Create html table with custom size of columns

Tags: html, css

I want to create html table but i cant assign a custom size of columns.
Here is my css code.

```
.styled-table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 25px 0;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.styled-table thead tr {
    background-color: getColor('azul-principal');
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: left;
}
.styled-table th,
.styled-table td {
    padding: 12px 15px;
}
// lineas de cada registro
.styled-table tbody tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

// Filas obscuras
.styled-table tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    color: getColor('azul-principal');
}
// Fin de la tabla linea 
.styled-table tbody tr:last-of-type {
    border-bottom: 2px solid getColor('azul-principal');
    
}
// Clase activa
.styled-table tbody tr.active-row {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: getColor('azul-principal');
}
```

Thanks for the help.
Here i put my css code for you to explain me where is the problem.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Can you share you html?

Comment: create a snippet with minimal code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+table+custum+width+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `width` CSS property to give the desired size for the table column.

```
.styled-table th,
.styled-table td {
    width: 300px;
}
```